# Is eigen_conversions deprecated?

Tags: ros, eigen, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [eigen_conversions](http://wiki.ros.org/eigen_conversions) package looks like the standard way to convert between eigen datatypes and standard ROS messages. However, [the functions](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/eigen_conversions/html/eigen__msg_8h.html#func-members) are all in the tf namespace. Does this make them deprecated along with the rest of tf2, or is it just an accident of history that they ended up in that namespace rather than something like "geometry" or "eigen"?

In any case, the geometry_experimental repo doesn't contain an equivalent.

I'm really just trying to write a simple dead-reckoning odometry publisher for encoder inputs. If I should be using KDL or tf2 for this task instead of Eigen, I'm totally open to suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101986/is-eigen_conversions-deprecated?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2013-11-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if it is deprecated, but it is certainly not commonly used (only 10 released packages depend on it, and most of those are moveit).

Personally, when doing kinematics-related things, I tend to use KDL over Eigen, as both are not terribly well documented, but at least the compile errors from KDL are mostly sane.

One other thing to be aware of with this package is that most of the conversions are from/to Eigen "double" types, which means it doesn't jive well with any PCL-related code (where everything is pretty much using Eigen "float" types). That is the main reason I have not used this package.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1